# How to resolve cgroup error when running docker container inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, cgroups, docker-in-docker

I am trying to run some multi-container build tests inside a running ubuntu docker container that I use to build my application (generally, I have a Gitlab CI setup).

I've found that when trying to run containers that specify a memory limit, I encounter errors like this:

```
ERROR: for <service-name>  Cannot start service <service-name>: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:385: applying cgroup configuration for process caused: cannot enter cgroupv2 "/sys/fs/cgroup/docker" with domain controllers -- it is in threaded mode: unknown
```

### Minimal Working Example

Here is a (nearly) minimal working example:

```
# start from ubuntu base image
docker run -it --privileged ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash

# once inside the container, install docker
apt-get update
apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
echo \
  "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
apt-get update
apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

# start docker daemon
/etc/init.d/docker stop # should already be stopped
dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 &

# run some container -- fails
docker run --memory=1gb eclipse-mosquitto:1.6

# run some container -- works
docker run eclipse-mosquitto:1.6
```

What I receive as an output (after pulling the image) is:

```
time="2022-01-27T01:23:20.018095900Z" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/424ce744b789f06b7f5ff94331df19b995e5de3ace50d4307b35886c9052f2a6 pid=4697
INFO[2022-01-27T01:23:20.064529100Z] shim disconnected                             id=424ce744b789f06b7f5ff94331df19b995e5de3ace50d4307b35886c9052f2a6
ERRO[2022-01-27T01:23:20.064613000Z] copy shim log                                 error="read /proc/self/fd/13: file already closed"
ERRO[2022-01-27T01:23:20.069022100Z] stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo 
ERRO[2022-01-27T01:23:20.072130600Z] stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo 
ERRO[2022-01-27T01:23:20.122636800Z] 424ce744b789f06b7f5ff94331df19b995e5de3ace50d4307b35886c9052f2a6 cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container 
ERRO[2022-01-27T01:23:20.123051000Z] Handler for POST /v1.41/containers/424ce744b789f06b7f5ff94331df19b995e5de3ace50d4307b35886c9052f2a6/start returned error: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:385: applying cgroup configuration for process caused: cannot enter cgroupv2 "/sys/fs/cgroup/docker" with domain controllers -- it is in an invalid state: unknown 
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:385: applying cgroup configuration for process caused: cannot enter cgroupv2 "/sys/fs/cgroup/docker" with domain controllers -- it is in an invalid state: unknown.
ERRO[0004] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

### Possible Solution

One [option](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) I've come across is, when running the base container, I should mount this `/var/run/docker.sock` volume, i.e.:

```sh
docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --privileged ubuntu:18.04 /bin/bash
```

which I guess basically [latches onto the host machine's docker daemon](https://techoverflow.net/2021/01/12/how-to-fix-gitlab-ci-error-during-connect-post-http-docker2375-v1-40-auth-dial-tcp-lookup-docker-on-no-such-host/) (my understanding may not be quite right here).
However, as mentioned above, I am using a Gitlab CI setup and mounting this volume into the runner's container is not a practical solution for me (as it requires [runner-specific configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-socket-binding)).

### Another Alternative

What I've also come across the is more "standard" [docker-in-docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) (dind) approach, which again works fine provided I mount that `docker.sock` volume into the container, i.e.:

```sh
# start from dind base image
docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --privileged docker:dind /bin/sh

# run mqtt -- works
docker run --memory=1gb eclipse-mosquitto:1.6
```

### My Request

Is there any solution that would allow me to get this multi-container setup to work under the following constraints?

1. I cannot mount `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` into the base container.
2. I cannot remove the memory limit in the inside containers.

Comment: Can you start this sequence from outside a container?  The setup required to run a second Docker daemon inside a container is fairly complex, and the [canonical advice](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) is to avoid it in CI environments.

Comment: In principle, yes - I am experimenting with using the gitlab "shell" executor instead of a docker executor for the CI runner. But, the shared runner I would like to use only provides a docker executor for the CI runner, so the goal of this question is to see if its possible to fix this issue within that existing setup (i.e., where I can't change anything about the CI runner configuratio)

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/6659, especially https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/38805f20f9bcc5e87869d6c79d432b166e1c88b4/hack/dind#L28-L38:

```bash
# cgroup v2: enable nesting
if [ -f /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.controllers ]; then
    # move the processes from the root group to the /init group,
    # otherwise writing subtree_control fails with EBUSY.
    # An error during moving non-existent process (i.e., "cat") is ignored.
    mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/init
    xargs -rn1 < /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.procs > /sys/fs/cgroup/init/cgroup.procs || :
    # enable controllers
    sed -e 's/ / +/g' -e 's/^/+/' < /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.controllers \
        > /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control
fi
```

(With modern v2 cgroups, you have to enable nesting for this to work.)

Comment: I'm struggling to enable this on DIND. I checked both links, and i see that inside DIND there is dind binary available that includes this code. When I run it i see bunch of "echo: write error: Not supported".  Any idea what is going on?

Comment: @StrahinjaDjurić are you running inside a user namespace or something like that?  (rootless host Docker, perhaps?)